# Objective-C: Loop through array of objects and remove objects which match a value in another array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, for-loop

I have 2 arrays, one contains a set of ID's and one contains a set of objects (similar to below):

```
NSArray *identifierArray = @[@100, @200, @300];
NSArray *peopleArray = @[@{@"id": @100, @"name": @"Ben"}, @{@"id": @200, @"name": @"Alex"}, @{@"id": @300, @"name": @"Sarah"}, @{@"id": @400,@"name": @"George"}, @{@"id": @500, @"name": @"Jessica"}];
```

I want to be able to loop through the `peopleArray` and check if any of the objects has an ID that appears in `identifierArray`. If a match is found, it should remove the object from the `identifierArray`, which would result in:

```
NSArray *peopleArray = @[@{@"id": @400,@"name": @"George"}, @{@"id": @500, @"name": @"Jessica"}];
```

I've tried some variations of for loops to loop through each object, then loop through each ID in `peopleArray`, as below, but it doesn't remove any objects, even though there are objects it should be removing.

```
    for (NSNumber *id in activePeople) {
        for (int i = 0; i < peopleArray.count; i++) {
            if (id == [peopleArray[i] valueForKey:@"id"]) {
                NSLog(@"Should remove...%@")
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of how i might go about this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this homework question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to drop loops and use the more contemporary block based API `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` (which actually exists since 2009 in macOS 10.6 Snow Leopard and iOS 4.0 ).

```
NSArray *identifierArray = @[@100, @200, @300];
NSMutableArray *array = [@[@{@"id": @100, @"name": @"Ben"}, @{@"id": @200, @"name": @"Alex"}, @{@"id": @300, @"name": @"Sarah"}, @{@"id": @400,@"name": @"George"}, @{@"id": @500, @"name": @"Jessica"}] mutableCopy];
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [identifierArray containsObject:obj[@"id"]];
}];
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Or still more efficient filtering the array with a predicate (available since macOS 10.4 Tiger and iOS 3.0 in 2005(!))

```
NSArray *identifierArray = @[@100, @200, @300];
NSArray *array = @[@{@"id": @100, @"name": @"Ben"}, @{@"id": @200, @"name": @"Alex"}, @{@"id": @300, @"name": @"Sarah"}, @{@"id": @400,@"name": @"George"}, @{@"id": @500, @"name": @"Jessica"}];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", identifierArray];
NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

If the `id` values should be strings replace all occurrences of `@x00` with `@"x00"`

Comment: Given both a try but both seem to not remove the objects with an ID of 100, 200 or 300. I must be missing something...

Comment: Both snippets are supposed to work stand-alone. Are the IDs really `NSNumber` objects?

Comment: Ah, think i may have solved it using the predicate example you gave, just changing `predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", identifierArray]` to `predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", identifierArray]`. If you can update your answer, i'll happily accept, hopefully help someone else out in the future. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want to **keep** 400 and 500 as described in the question the code is correct, `@"id == %@", identifierArray` cannot work.

Comment: Ah, as you mention it, i just printed the data type of the `id` in the `array` in the example and it's actually `NSTaggedPointerString`, and the `id` in `identifierArray` is `__NSCFNumber` which must be why it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Works perfectly, my fault... matched the two data types and works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You very likely cannot use == to compare the two objects in this case, but instead use isEqual:

== compares the values of pointers. In your case it seems that they will not be the same.

isEqual: instead compares the objects itself.

To reuse your code you can try this:

```
for (NSNumber *id in activePeople) {
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleArray.count; i++) {
        if ([id isEqual:[peopleArray[i] valueForKey:@"id"]) {
            NSLog(@"Should remove...%@")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just given this a try but doesn't seem to remove the object (/ the NSLog is not printing to the console)?